# Can you make a python script behave differently when imported than when run directly?

Tags: python

I often have to write data parsing scripts, and I'd like to be able to run them in two different ways: as a module and as a standalone script. So, for example:

```
def parseData(filename):
    # data parsing code here
    return data

def HypotheticalCommandLineOnlyHappyMagicFunction():
    print json.dumps(parseData(sys.argv[1]), indent=4)
```

the idea here being that in another python script I can call `import dataparser` and have access to `dataParser.parseData` in my script, or on the command line I can just run `python dataparser.py` and it would run my `HypotheticalCommandLineOnlyHappyMagicFunction` and shunt the data as json to stdout. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to guard the code that should be only run when the script is called stand-alone by

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Your main script code
```

The code after this `if` won't be run if the module is imported.

The `__name__` special variable contains the name of the current module as a string.  If your file is called `glonk.py`, then `__name__` will be `"glonk"` if the the file is imported as a module and it will be `"__main__"` if the file is run as a stand-alone script.